# hyperlink with param

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

```
<a href="#" id="secondpage">Hyperlink</a>
```

I have hyperlink to load current pages like this,and Can i try to put one or more param in this hyperlink ?

Example

```
 <a href="#?id=1" id="secondpage">Hyperlink</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be

```
<a href="?id=1#" id="secondpage">Hyperlink</a>
```

because `#something` is always a hash and searches for an ID with that value.

Comment: @SacVan You're welcome. Please accept answers that solved your problem to show others what's the solution.